# What is the definition of this statistic?

Tags: standard-deviation, error

For a data set that is Gaussian distributed, $\sigma$ defines the standard-deviation of the distribution. My question is, what is the correct indention or terminology for the following: 
$$\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2N-2}} \text{.}$$

My interpretation is that it is the "error" in the standard deviation, $\sigma$. Is this a correct way to view this?

Comment: To help you clarify your question, note that this is not quite a statistic because it's not a function of the data alone (sigma can't be computed from the data, only estimated).  Second, where did this quantity arise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to distinguish between the true population value of a parameter of a statistical distribution and the estimate of that value obtained from a sample of size $N$. The symbol $\sigma$ is conventionally used to represent the population standard deviation, the square root of the population variance $\sigma^2$. A sample estimate of the variance is conventionally represented as $s^2$ and a sample estimate of the standard deviation as $s$.

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/156518/28500) shows the formula for the standard error of estimates of the variance, $s^2$, when sampling from a normal distribution. The [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/157305/28500) to that question shows a way to convert such standard error estimates of $s^2$ to standard error estimates of $s$ that holds in the limit of large sample sizes for sampling from any of a large class of distributions. A bit of math shows that if you replace $\sigma$ in your formula with $s$ you have the corresponding formula for the standard error of the sample standard deviation in the case of a normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks @EdM, this was a great answer!