# Using $\chi^2$ result to find asymptotic distribution of $S^2$ when $X_i$ normally distributed

Tags: distributions, sampling, central-limit-theorem, asymptotics

At the end of [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/105338/106860) it is mentioned that

> Note: the above result of course holds also for normally distributed samples -but in this last case we have also available a finite-sample chi-square distributional result.

What is this result? If possible, can someone provide an illustration (or a link/reference to an illustration) where this $\chi^2$ result is used?

Comment: The $\chi^2$ distribution usually arises as a (multiple of a) sum of squares of zero-mean normal variables.  This basic result is at the foundation of $\chi^2$ tests and F-ratio tests in ANOVA, the Student t test, and much more.  You can find out more about this from, say, the Wikipedia page on the $\chi^2$ distribution or by searching our site.

Comment: See also Cochran's Theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem