# Asymptotic distribution of sample variance of uncorrelated non-normal sample

Tags: variance, asymptotics, central-limit-theorem

I know from [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105337/asymptotic-distribution-of-sample-variance-of-non-normal-sample), that Asymptotic distribution of sample variance of i.i.d non-normal sample that the sample variance $s^2$ is distributed as follows:
$$\sqrt n(s^2 - \sigma^2) \rightarrow_d N\left(0,\mu_4 - \sigma^4\right)\;\; $$

My question is, does this still hold in the case where instead of having independent random variables, we have **uncorrelated** random variables?