# Limiting distribution of sample variance and standard deviation

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, standard-deviation, asymptotics, central-limit-theorem

I have a centered Gaussian sample of $n$ elements $X_i,\,i=1,..,n$, with variance $\sigma^2$. I would like to find the limiting distribution of the sample variance $\sigma_n^2=\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ and of $\sqrt n(\sigma_n-\sigma)$, using the Central Limit Theorem. Thank you.

Comment: This has been asked and answered in this site, here is one answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105337/asymptotic-distribution-of-sample-variance-of-non-normal-sample/203697#203697. Do you know about the delta method?

Comment: Actually, in the post you pointed to, it seems that they do not obtain the limit distribution of $\sqrt n (\sigma_n - \sigma)$, but of the same expression valid for the variance. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @marco you can use the delta method to convert between the two: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Univariate_delta_method