# The Standard Error of Mean (SEM) and Non-normal sampling distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, standard-error

I know that as the sample size increases, the sampling distribution of the mean will become normally distributed, even if the population data are skewed (non-normal). So we can safely assume that the sampling distribution of the mean will be fairly normal.

However, I was wondering what happens if the shape of the sampling distribution is somehow non-normal (it might be oblivious to us) and its associated SEM? Is the SEM going to be misleading for calculating the confidence intervals and significance testing?

Comment: Please give an example of a sampling distribution that is non-normal.  It seems to me you might be talking about small-sample sampling distributions.

Comment: @GreggH Some kind of infinite variance distribution?

Comment: @GreggH yes, I have been mainly thinking about small-sample sampling distributions

Comment: @e.erhan ¿are you considering distributions with undefined (infinite) variance?

Comment: is this what you are asking? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105337/asymptotic-distribution-of-sample-variance-of-non-normal-sample

Comment: @M.Austin this link answers my question (I suppose, but I will read it in detail). thanks!