# Correcting for systematic bias in test size

Tags: hypothesis-testing, central-limit-theorem, asymptotics, asymptotic-covariance

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be iid random variables with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and let $$\xi:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n (X^2_i-\sigma^2).$$

Then, by the standard CLT, we have $\xi\Rightarrow N(0,v) $ as $n\to \infty$, where $v=\sigma^4(\kappa-1)$ and $\kappa$ is the kurtosis. Suppose I estimate $v$ with the consistent estimator

$$\hat{v}:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X^4_i-(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i)^2$$

and do a right-tailed test at the level $\alpha$ for the following null and alternative hypotheses: $$H_0:E[X^2_i]=\sigma^2$$
$$H_1:E[X^2_i]>\sigma^2,$$
which means I reject $H_0$ if $\xi$ is greater than the $1-\alpha$ quantile of the $N(0,\hat{v})$ distribution.

Simulations with $n=1000$ reveal that the test is systematically undersized, which I think is due to the asymmetry of the function $x^2$. On the other hand the bilateral test against the alternative $H_1:E[X^2_i]\neq \sigma^2$ appears correctly sized on average. So one possibility
would be to do a bilateral test in any case, but this sacrifices a bit of power against unilateral alternatives.

Are there other solutions? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Are you forced to use $\xi$ as the test statistic?

Comment: @J.Delaney What other statistic do you have in mind?

Comment: Since your hypothesis is about the mean of $X$, why not use the sample mean?

Comment: @J.Delaney Oh yes sorry this was a typo. The hypothesis is about $E[X_i^2]$. I made an edit to my post.

Comment: Under the null hypothesis $\sum X_i^2$ has a $\chi^2$ distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom, so you can do an exact test

Comment: @J.Delaney Correct, but what if the $X_i$ are independent but not normally distributed?

Comment: If you assume the $X_i$ are centered than your hypothesis is about their variance, see a related question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105337/asymptotic-distribution-of-sample-variance-of-non-normal-sample